# An example of a non hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, poincare-duality, non-orientable-surfaces

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Show that there exist nonorientable $1$-dimensional manifold if the Hausdorff condition is dropped from the definition of a manifold.

I know this question is here [Non-orientable one dimensional manifold.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353695/non-orientable-one-dimensional-manifold) but I am asking about a different thing:

What is the meaning of a line with 2 origins? Why it is not a hausdorff space?

I found an explanation online saying that the line with two origins is defined as follows: Take two copies of the real line, say $\mathbb R_1$ and $\mathbb R_2$ and identify every point in $\mathbb R_1$ with the corresponding point in $\mathbb R_2$ except for the origin.

Does this means the drawing of this space is as follows:

[image]?

Comment: It looks *sorta* like that, but crucially, that part where the blue line separates from the black doesn't exist. It's more like you copied the origin and they both coexist at the exact same place, which is hard to draw.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take neighborhoods $N_1,N_2$ about $0_1,0_2$ respectively. They must intersect as they both contain some small $\epsilon>0$. Thus the space is not Hausdorff as the copies of zero cannot be separated by open sets.